Where is the context menu for the code editor window in the menu customize dialog in Visual Studio 2022?
When in a code editor window and you right click on the page the following context menu appears.

I have looked through the customize dialog Context menu options 4-5 times yet I don't see it there. Is this menu not listed for some reason or am I missing something?

I have done customizing in the SQL Server Management Studio code editors context menu which was no problems to find, but VS is being elusive.
